# Using generics in GTK# widgets

Tags: generics, widget, gtk#

Has anybody ever tried to use generics for a GTK# widget?

I am playing with the idea of creating a widget that consists of a combobox with two buttons right next to it, one for editing the selected item, the other to create a new item. Obviously this would make the most sense if the type of item is generic, as otherwise the widget wouldn't be very useful, or I would have to make it an abstract widget and then create a large number of subtypes, which isn't great, either.

In consequence I am wondering whether anybody has already tried this. As far as I can see there's nothing in the language spec that would prevent it. I suppose the UI designer in monodevelop will probably hiss at me, but I can live with that, as long as the widget as such 
is fully functional.

Comment: I have no idea why you think this requires generics.  A combo box is just a set of strings.

Comment: In its very simplest form, yes. In more advanced forms it displays the "name" property of all the items that can be selected for a particular purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You only have to make sure your generic class implements an interface that has your shown property.

```
public partial class ExampleWidget<T> : Gtk.Bin where T: INote
{
    private T model;

    public ComboBoxItem (T model)
    {
        this.Build ();
        this.model = model;
        label1.Text = model.Description;
    }
}
```

Also you have to make the designer created File generic and you have to stop working with the designer, because it will allways override the class to be nongeneric.
So design your Widget and make it than generic.